# How to check code style formatting in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to check code style in the whole project or some part of it in IDEA? Let me make an accent here on a word "check". I don't need to fix code style I just want to see how big is the problem of not following code style in the project. So I want to see list of lines or cases where code formatting is not inline with what I have set in the File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java. I thought that Code Inspection does this but when I checked File -> Settings -> Inspections -> Code style issues it seemed to me that these issues are not about code style formatting.

What I would like to use is: I start some inspection on some part of code or the whole project and as a result of inspection I want to see list of issues/lines where code formatting is broken.
I know I might just reformat the whole project and then run source control diff but I don't think that this is really good. I would like to see some categorization of code style issues with statistics, etc... Is there any way to get this in IDEA?

Comment: Ok, so way you get 10,000 violations, what are you going to do with that information?

Comment: I'll show to managers and tell them to relax about some small formatting problems they find in ongoing commits. The practical use I see - I would prohibit myself to commit the code with broken formatting. Similar to what currently done with Inspection: if you switch on checkbox in commit dialog your changes will be inspected and all issues will be brought to your attention before commit.

Comment: Can you just hit ctrl-alt-L and do a diff?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html). It analyses the code and shows summary similar to error or warning message in the IDE. In addition you could customize the check style or use existing one. There should be a plugin for IDEA as well.

Comment: It doesn't follow the Code Style I have setup in IDEA, does it?

Comment: I've checked it's documentation: "A plug-in for JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA 12 which provides real-time feedback against a given CheckStyle (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) profile by way of an inspection". So it's against CheckStyle profile - not the Code Style IDEA settings...

Answer (score 1):

Try out [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/). It's based on the [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). You can create configuration to run it under IntelliJ IDEA.

The output looks like:

```
C:\src\ClassPathTldsLoader.java:8:8: Unused import - java.util.Collections.
C:\src\model\Class1.java:64: 'if' construct must use '{}'s.
C:\src\model\Class2.java:55: 'if' construct must use '{}'s.
C:\src\Class3.java:4:1: Redundant import from the same package - java.util.Collections
...
```